# TelerikMvcExtensions Grid filter when using ViewModels

Tags: c#, lambda, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to figure out the  easiest way to filter my grid.

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid<MyViewModel>()
     .Name("Grid")
     .Filterable();
```

I'm using ViewModels in my View and DomainModels in my Controller. I map between them using AutoMapper.
Problem is that the Telerik grid wasn't designed to work with ViewModels so the filter logic gets messed up :(

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public JsonResult SelectHandled(GridCommand command)
{
    var items = _repository.AsQueriable()
                    .Where(command.FilterDescriptors) // <-------- this won't work
                    .Page(command.Page, command.PageSize);

    var vms = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyModel>, IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>(items);

    var model = new GridModel
    {
        Data = vms,
        Total = // omitted
    };
    return Json(model);
}
```

How do I map the `FilterDescriptors` for `MyViewModel` to `MyModel`?

I essentially want to implement my own [IFilterDescriptor Extension](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/m_telerik_web_mvc_extensions_queryableextensions_where.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can return all the records from the controller and Telerik grid manage the filtering logic at its own. From your code, you can try it like:

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult SelectHandled(GridCommand command)
{
    IEnumerable<MyViewModel> items = _repository.Get();

    var vms = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyModel>, IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>(items);

   var retColl = new GridModel(vms) { Total = command.PageSize * command.Page };
   return View(retColl);
}
```

Comment: That would only do client side filtering. So for that to work I'd have to send the entire list to the client which is not going to work.

Comment: If you are going to fetch all the records from db and then trying to apply filtering manually using `.Where(command.FilterDescriptors)` then I don't think there will be much of performance gain. So I would still prefer to return all the records and let the grid handle the filtering logic by itself only to avoid complexity.

Comment: `_repository.Get()` should have been `_repository.AsQueriable()`. Corrected the post. So it is filtered on the database.